# Org mode capture template for repeat tasks

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I want to capture several tasks that will repeat annually from the date on which they are captured.

So, I did:

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(("a" "TODO Item that repeats annually" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/todo.org" "Annual")
       "* TODO %?\n SCHEDULED: %t")))
```

This adds a TODO with scheduled date as today. How do I get `+1y` added to scheduled?

On a more general note, what should the capture template be with schedule for tomorrow, tomorrow recurring annually, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that using [template expansion](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html#Template-expansion). As `%(EXP)` will expand a lisp expression, you can take advantage of it.

Rewriting the template's scheduled part to this will do it

```lisp
SCHEDULED: %(concat \"<\" (format-time-string \"%Y-%m-%d\") \" +1y\>\")
```

<strike>Surely there is a more general "org-way" to do it if you dig enough into timestamp objects, but I haven't been able to figure how to make it work with `org-insert-timestamp` as `PRE` and `POST` are inserted out of timestamp;</strike>

Also, you can use `org-insert-time-stamp`'s (stated but undocumented) `EXTRA` argument to pass it, so:

```lisp
SCHEDULED: %(org-insert-time-stamp nil nil nil nil nil \" +1y\")
```

will do the same. For more complex date choices than current date probably using `org-read-date` will help.